# Método correto para pegar valor ComboBox populado por DataTable

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable

Qual a maneira correta para pegar o valor de um `ComboBox` populado por um `DataTable`?

Estou utilizando os seguinte código:

```
private void ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Consulta_cidade cidade = new Consulta_cidade();

    var dataRowView = this.comboBox3.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    var valor = dataRowView.Row.ItemArray[1];

    int a = Convert.ToInt32(valor);

    comboBox2.DataSource = cidade.consulta_cidade(a);
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "descricao";
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "descricao";
    comboBox2.Update();
}
```

Comment: Pode usar a propriedade `SelectedItem` para pegar o valor do display e a propriedade `SelectedValue` para pegar o código associado a valor do Display.

Comment: Dener, este metodo, não pode ser aplicado aqui, pois quando utilizamos um dataTable para popular um comboBox, os valores retornam como objeto, e não como string. Por isso tive a necessidade da utilização de um DataRowVIew. Me corriga se stiver errado. Obrigado

Comment: É WPF ou Winforms?

Comment: Dener estou trabalhando com WinForms

Comment: Onde o valor é retornado como um objeto?

Comment: Basta converter para inteiro: `int valor = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue);`

Comment: Dener, perfeito, refiz o código conforme você disse. e resolvi o problema. não sei pq, ontem não estava conseguindo. não consegui identificar o erro. Obrigado.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Poste isso como resposta.

Comment: @zekk sim vou postar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer a conversão para inteiro usando o método `ToInt32()` veja:

```
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue);
```